# Spaceship A and Spaceship B move in opposite directions at half the speed of light, and A fires a laser at B, does the laser light reach Spaceship B?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, laser

This question has been bugging me for a week now!

I believe it would, but logically, I feel like I'm missing something.

Please give a full explanation.

Comment: Well, why do you believe it would?

Comment: *"This question has been bugging me for a week now!"* - Have you tried drawing a spacetime diagram for this scenario?

Comment: @Alfred Cenaturi IMO That should be the answer!

Comment: Have you done basic searches on this site and Google on addition of velocity in relativity?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the light will reach $B$.  To see this, consider an observer $C$ relative to whom the velocity of $A$ is $v_{CA} = -c/2$ and the velocity of $B$ is $v_{CB} = c/2$.  Now change to a frame where $A$ is at rest: the velocity of $C$ with respect to $A$ is obviously $v_{AC} = c/2$.  Now we can use the Lorentz velocity addition formula to compute the velocity of $B$ with respect to $A$:

$$v_{AB} = \frac{v_{AC} + v_{CB}}{1 + \frac{v_{AC}v_{CB}}{c^2}}$$

And we can plug in the known values for $v_{AC}$ & $v_{CB}$ to get

$$\begin{align}
V_{AB} &= \frac{c/2 + c/2}{1 + \frac{c^2}{4c^2}}\\
       &= \frac{4c}{5}
\end{align}$$

So the velocity of $B$ with respect to $A$ is $4/5$th of the speed of light.  So the laser will reach $B$ from $A$.

Comment: May I know what is the role of observer C?

Comment: @user6760: C is merely the observer with respect to whom the two spaceships are moving at half the speed of light.

Answer (score 0):

In Newtonian dynamics, the speed of spaceship $B$ as observed from spaceship $A$ would be $\frac c 2 + \frac c 2 = c$, the speed of light. However, we know that Newtonian dynamics is not correct (although it is a good approximation for speeds very much slower than the speed of light).

Instead, addition of velocities in special relativity tells us that the speed of spaceship $B$ as observed from spaceship $A$ will be less than the speed of light (the formula for addition of velocities is give in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula)). So, yes, a laser beam fired from spaceship $A$ will catch up with spaceship $B$.